# How can I repair an underground gutter drain pipe broken at the face of a concrete slab?

Tags: plumbing, drainage, pvc, gutters, underground

I can't use couplers because there's cement around the pvc pipes. Its cracked right to the curb. How do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: PVC isn't black. That's either ABS or polypropylene. How wide is the sidewalk?

Answer (score 3):

Concrete is **not** immutable, just annoying to modify or remove/replace.

So, remove enough concrete that you can make the repair, and replace it when done.

**Or**, being just a storm drain to the curb, consider that *leaks don't matter much*, and just butt in sections of pipe with some filter fabric over to keep out most soil while directing the bulk of the water out to the curb. It's not like it was a sanitary sewer or a pressurized supply pipe. Heck, use perforated pipe (holes down, and solid, not corrugated.) Or use solid pipe you drill holes in the bottom of. Hold in place as you pack the soil back around them.